# Truncate sysmail_log due to 5mil records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table sysmail_log has more than 5,000,000 record. I try to truncate/delete all records simply running DELETE FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_log query.

The problem is this query seems never ends. I've run it for more than 12 hours but still in executing.

Why it is not working?

I want to drop and recreate the table again, but I am not sure about it.

Should I do it?

Comment: Is it progressing? I mean does it delete records at all or hung?

Comment: Have you tried deleting several rows from the beginning, e.g. `delete top(10) from msdb.dbo.sysmail_log order by log_id`?

Comment: After 12 hours I have to stop it. nothing happens.

Comment: Yes, I do, I try to delete top record. same thing!

Comment: You do know there is a truncate command?

Comment: Absolutely, I know truncate command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a process that has locked that table. It was a select query on sysmail_log.

I killed it. problem solved.

Founded the blocked process by EXEC sp_who2 and see the query result by 
DBCC INPUTBUFFER (247)